# Keep applied filters angular 5

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-routing

I need to keep applied filters. When I change component and when I return to the previous component, I would like the filters to be applied already.What is the best way to do it?

Comment: I'd suggest treating the router as the single source of truth. So any time the filters change update the url (queryParams), and in the component OnInit update the filters from the url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use many ways to do this like route params, queryParams, observables and localstorage.

I preferred to use the same route and update your filters value, so you can get it from queryParams.

for Example :

```
this._activatedRoute.queryParams.subscribe(param => {    
                    if (param['filterResults']) {
                        //:TODO
                    }
                });
```

or you can use subject observables

```
// angular
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';
import { Subscriber } from 'rxjs/Subscriber';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class MyService {
    events: any[];
    // Observable string sources
    emitDataChange= new Subject<any>();
    // Service message commands
    currentData = this.emitDataChange.asObservable();

    constructor(
        private http: appHttpService
    ) {
    }

    emitData(value: any) {
        this.emitDataChange.next(value);
    }
}
```

Or use local storage for get and set filters

> Page1.ts

```
gotoStudentDetails(stId: any) {
    let stFilter: any = JSON.stringify({
      advanceFilter: this.advanceFilterValue,
      currentPageIndex: this.currentPageIndex,
      prevPage: 'st-list'
    });
    localStorage.setItem('stFilter', stFilter);
    this._router.navigateByUrl('/std/st-details/' + stId);
  }
```

> Page2.ts

```
ngOnInit() {
    if (localStorage.getItem('stFilter')) {
      let stFilter: any = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('stFilter'));
      if (stFilter && stFilter.prevPage === 'st-list') {
        this.advanceFilterValue = stFilter.advanceFilter;
        this.currentPageIndex = stFilter.currentPageIndex;
      }
    }

    //:TODO
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest treating the router as a source of truth.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import {map} from 'rxjs/operators/map';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
  <select  [ngModel]="selected" (ngModelChange)="onSelectedChange($event)">
    <option *ngFor="let option of options" [value]="option">{{option}}</option>
  </select>
  `,
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  options = [
    'one', 'two', 'three'
  ]

  selected = 'one'

  private defaultSelectValue = 'one';

  constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.activatedRoute.queryParams.pipe(map(({selected}) => selected ||  this.defaultSelectValue))
      .subscribe(selected => this.selected = selected)
  }

  onSelectedChange(selected: string) {
    this.router.navigate([], { queryParams: { selected }})
  }
}
```

1. In `ngOnInit` we subscribe to queryParams changes and update the component `selected` value. `[ngModel]` will keep the `<select>` value in sync.
2. On `ngModelChange` we navigate to the same same component, but with different queryParams. It will trigger the queryParams stream we subscribed to before in `ngOnInit`.

Now any time you navigate somewhere else, and then press the back button, the select will always go back to the previously selected value. Another benefit of using the router as a source of truth is that you can bookmark the url.

[Live demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-easlnj). Play around with `?selected=one` in the url. Change it to `?selected=two` and see how the input starts with the correct value.

Comment: what if the object is too bing , and i want to save state of full grid object like if i use ag-grid and want to save state of it ..this will not work..better to use route for sending information which is important not for sending filtering things

Comment: In that case you can use a service to keep the state.

Comment: You need localstorage for it as its client side data and not much valuable information ...

Comment: The OP does not mention closing the app. Only navigating around in his angular app. In that case we do not need to involve the localStorage. But of course it is a valid option :)